# How to send data to kryonet outside java

Tags: java, kryo, kryonet

trying to understand how to work with kryonet, it is quite easy to send and receive message from java client, but what if I want to send it from some UI tool like Hercules, or not java code. As I see it uses kryo for Serialization, is there way to serialize object to this fromat without java? Or use plain String or json for comunication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a server using json instead of kryo:

```java
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.serialization.JsonSerialization;

new Server(16384, 2048, new JsonSerialization());
```